# Como pegar parametros na URL atraves do AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Galera eu tenho uma URL da seguinte forma "teste/#/app/produto/2" e eu queria pegar esse numero no final da URL e usar ela para fazer uma condição como eu faço para trazer esse ID?

Comment: Você esta usando `ngRoute` ou `ui-router` para criar rotas com variáveis?

Comment: Uso o ui-router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que esse 2 foi definido como uma variável de rota

```
.state('produtoView', {
    url: '/produto/:id' ...
```

Você pode resgatar essa variável `id` injetando o `$stateParams` na sua controller e pegando o valor da variável da rota pelo nome dela `$stateParams.id`.

De uma olhada na documentação do [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/modules/ng1.html#_stateparams), logo abaixo ele fala de uma nova maneira de buscar a variável nas novas versões do ui-router, então o `$stateParams` está depreciado.

Não coloquei da maneira nova pois também não sabia deste fato.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o serviço `$location`.

Por exemplo, para uma dada URL `http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo`:

```
var abUl = $location.absUrl();     // => "http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
var url  = $location.url();        // => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
var prot = $location.protocol();   // => "http"
var host = $location.host();       // => "example.com"
var path = $location.path();       // => "/some/path"
var srch = $location.search();     // => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

No seu caso específico, $location.path() retornará `/app/produto/2`.

[Fonte.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)